# What is the product of the reaction between alcohol and acetyl chloride in presence of pyridine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, esters

What happens when butan-2-ol reacts(under heat) with $\ce{CH3COCl}$ in the presence of pyridine? Does it form $\ce{CH3COOCH(CH3)CH2CH3}$? I got the ester mentioned but the solution says it gives an alkene. What is the product when an alcohol reacts with an acid chloride in the presence of pyridine?

Comment: How much pyridine and at what temperature?

Comment: These are standard acylation conditions for alcohols done at ice-bath or room temperature, so unless it is being heating strongly in the presence of a large excess of pyridine I doubt you're going to get an alkene. What is the source that says you will?

Comment: @Waylander The amount of pyridine is not mentioned but the the reaction proceeds under heating.

Comment: In what solvent at what temperature?

Answer (score 4):

I found that the reaction you describe is a special form of the [Schotten-Baumann reaction.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schotten%E2%80%93Baumann_reaction)

The special form of the reaction is called *[Einhorn-Acylierung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einhorn-Acylierung)* ("Unicorn acylation" in English). It is named after the chemist Albert Einhorn (*Einhrorn* means "unicorn" in German and hence the reaction name).

The reaction mechanism is as follows:

First, the pyridine forms an acetyl pyridinium salt. The alcohol can then perform a nucloephilic attack. The pyridine gets removed and can remove one hydrogen to reach the final product.

[image: Einhorn Acylation CC BY-SA 4.0]

Image source: [From the German Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einhorn-Acylierung#/media/Datei:Einhorn-Acylierung_RMV5.svg)